# Hibernate session is not initialized at startup

Tags: java, spring, web-services, hibernate

I use hibernate templates with spring (DB2, C3P0)

application starts but connection is not opened.
After first query from client c3p0 init kicks in and actually open the connection. But that takes 2-3 seconds whitch noticable slows down first client during its own startup.

How to force hibernate to open db at startup?

Code [EDIT]

```
  <bean id=hibernateproperties >
<property name="properties">
    <props>
     <prop key="hibernate hbm2ddl|dialect|query.substitutions|show_sql </prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.c3po.minPoolSize">1</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.c3po.maxPoolsize">5</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.c3po.timeout">500</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.c3po.max_statements">50</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.c3po.testconnectionOnCheckout">true</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.c3po.minActive">1</prop>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id=sessionfactory 
    class=AnnotationSessionFactory 
    properties=hibernateproperties 
    dataSource=c3p0dataSource>
    <property name="packagesToScan" >
        <list>
            <value>myPackages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In log there is no initialization of c3p0 Until I manually create query.

[EDIT]
I debug code and when SessionFactory.getSession() is called it will findout that session is not created at all and initialize session with c3p0. Before actual query  there is log line
Initializing c3p0 pool (with class and options).
My guess that AnnotationSessionFactory use lazy approach to session init.

NOTE:
I set spring lazy bean init to false

Comment: Do you use it in a Server?

Comment: @AdamArold thanks for poinitng out. Code section was somehow invisible. Now it should be fixed.

Comment: @PeterRader i tried both - win desktop and linux server. Both 64b

Comment: What matters is how you have configured the c3p0 DataSource.

Comment: @JBNizet i believe you are not right. I tried to force non zero number of active connections but after debugging c3p0 is not even started befor you call getSession

Comment: Please add the actual configuration of c3p0 datasource and session factory.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov - done. I was on tablet and this kind of writing is horrible there. Also I believe it is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

c3p0 seems doesn't support warm up. So one of the possible options is to configure c3p0 to never close some small number of connections and do manual warm up on application start.

You may need to set `maxIdleTimeExcessConnections` option so c3p0 close extra idle connections and set `minPoolSize` to some small value (default is 3).

Use any method to do post initialization actions: [beans post processor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp), any of [start-up callbacks](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-combined-effects) with dependency to dataSource.

This action should open connection and then close it: this will create one (or more depending on c3p0 `acquireIncrement` parameter) connection and put it back to pool. Here is example using `@PostConstruct` annotation:

```
@Service
class C3P0Warmer {
  @Autowired DataSource dataSource;

  @PostConstruct
  public warmup() {
      JdbcUtils.closeConnection(dataSource.getConnection()); 
  }
}
```

Comment: c3p0 is not even started. As I did not configure it as standalone DataSource. 
I injected c3p0 config directly to the session and it will handle datasource. However I use exactly same approach to request session which trigger initialization - I consider that as hack and looking for better way.

This is good hint. I will try to make c3po as standalone DS and try-out.